# How can i add a second argument on Jsoup getImages method

Tags: java, image, web-scraping, download, jsoup

I'm using the method below to retrieve images from a website,and i want to add a unique id to each image.

How can i do that.

```
private static void getImages(String src) throws IOException {
    String folder = null;

    //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (indexname == src.length()) {
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());
    System.out.println(name);

    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ name));
    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the awnser :

```
private static void getImages(String src,String UrName) throws IOException {
    String folder = "Folder url";

    //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (indexname == src.length()) {
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ "/" +UrName+ ".jpg"));

    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```